# i cannot be resolved to a variable in a for loop

Tags: java, loops

I have an exercise where I have to create a method that takes an array of length 365 (days in a year) and returns the index (day) with the lowest value (lowest temperature). I'm new to java and I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
 public class Temperature {

    public static int coldest(double[] temperatures) {
        double coldestDay = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<temperatures.length; i++); {
            if (temperatures[i] < coldestDay) {
                coldestDay = i;
            } return coldestDay;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] thisYear = new double[365];

        thisYear[45] = -6;

        System.out.println(thisYear[45]);

        System.out.println(Temperature.coldest(thisYear));
        }
}
```

At the moment I'm getting: `i cannot be resolved to a variable`. I have looked at some questions with the same problem on here but I'm still not really understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<temperatures.length; i++);` - remove the `;`

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! what about the return statement? I'm getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int` but it should be returning the index as an int anyway right?

Comment: Change return type to double. Or you can down case double to int, but that may cause data lose.

Comment: In the condition block, you are assigning a `double` to an `int`. Are you sure it's `coldestDay = i` and not `coldestDay = temperatures[i]`? Meaning, are you returning the index of the day of the coldest temperature or are you getting the coldest temperature itself?

Comment: @Shankhadeep Ghoshal Sorry I should have been more clear, I want it tor return the index of the day

Comment: Your IDE should warn you about this.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `;` after the `for()` and move the return out of the for loop.

```java
public static int coldest(double[] temperatures) {
    int coldestDay = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<temperatures.length; i++){
        if (temperatures[i] < temparatures[coldestDay]) {
            coldestDay = i;
        } 
    }
    return coldestDay;
}
```

Comment: What about the casting the loop counter to `double`?  You'll get a compile time error there.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal What I understand from his code is that he **wants** the index, not the temperature itself, so it's still an int.

Comment: that still doesn't solve "assigning a double to an int" problem. You'll get the compile time error as well. What you can do is change the `coldestDay` to an `int`. You need the index of the day only, right? So that should do it.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal I already did an edit, `coldestDay` is now an int

Answer (score 0):

You need another reference for the temperature and to move the return at the end of the loop

```
public static int coldest(double[] temperatures) {
    double lowestTemp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int coldestDay = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<temperatures.length; i++) {
        if (temperatures[i] < lowestTemp) {
            lowestTemp = temperatures[i]
            coldestDay = i;
        } 
    }
    return coldestDay;
}
```

I think your sintax problem was related to the semi-colon after the fori declaration and the missing after the `coldestDay` integer

When you are trying to get the lowest `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is used so you make sure your initial value doesn't break the solution, by example if you use `0` what happens if there are no lower temps than zero. And viceversa for getting the highest value `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: You are not updating the `lowestTemp`, also you are not really using it. So, you could just remove it and it will be fine and simply use the `coldestDay` to compare with the value at the current index. Also, your condition is always true. In a nutshell, the logic itself isn't right. Please review.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal thanks for noticing it, and I do think the temperature is needed because if the code is `if the value of the temperature is lower than the coldest day index` that doesn't make sense, the index is one thing and the temperature is another. We only have to update the index if the temperature is lower

Comment: Well, you are right. In this case the OP simply is asking for the index and it's just one variable less. Although it doesn't really matter, a single local variable that is so yea, basically you and @THess have the same logic so it's all good.

Comment: Ho! I see the solution you mention, pretty clever actually

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should start from second element ( `**i=1**` ) as coldestDay is set to 0 index at the beginning. @THess

```
public static int coldest(double[] temperatures) 
{
    int coldestDay = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<temperatures.length; i++)
    {
        if (temperatures[i] < temparatures[coldestDay]) 
        {
            coldestDay = i;
        } 
    }

    return coldestDay;
}
```

Comment: Not really. What if the coldest day in the array is on position 0 and the 2nd coldest day is on day n. If you set `i`  as 1 you just skip day 0 unnecessarily and you might even get the incorrect data.

Comment: What do you mean by day n? This code is absolutely fine. We are considering each and every values in the array.

Comment: By day n I mean some other day in the array (that isn't 0). And no, we're not considering each and every value in the array in your code. 
To test that you can set these values and let your code run. `temperatures[0] = -10;`

`temperatures[20] = -8;`

If day 0 is being considered, then your output from running this code should be `0`, if day 0 is not being considered, then your output from running the code should be `20`.

Comment: Run my code with whatever input you have, get the output and then say if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: I just did, and you're right, sorry for saying that you were wrong. But I still think it's kinda odd to set it to 1 even though the result doesn't make a difference whether or not the starting index is 0 or 1.

Comment: Its never odd to set i = 1. We don't need to set i=0 all the time. Yes both code are correct. Setting i=1, will work (n-1) times, where n is the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: `i++);` shouldn't have a `;` and your `return` should be outside the `for` loop.